# Python backtrace from C++

Tags: c++, python, debugging

I have some Python code that calls into C++.  Is there a way to retrieve the Python backtrace and not just the C++ one from a point inside the C++ code?

Answer (score 1):

I think the magic word you're looking for is [traceback](http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html).

If you know you're looking for `traceback.extract_stack()`, can you figure out the API calls yourself?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any inherent way to do so, but why not just get the stacktrace from pythoncode?

It's pretty simple to call python from C++ and there's the handy [traceback](http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html) module for this stuff.